# Reading multiple #Temp table select in C# by its name

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have multiple temp tables in SQL Server and I want to Select all of them in one query; like this:

```
select * from #temp1
select * from #temp2
select * from #temp3
```

Is there a way in C#, to get the result table by its name or alias? (not by index)

**Edit:** All tables are different from each other.

Comment: What do you mean? That isn't one query, it is three of them. And not really sure what you mean about the c# part. Are you returning this to a DataSet or something? You need to provide some sort of context and details here.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, I want to get all result in multiple tables and one dataset (or  an alternative) at one time

Comment: This will produce 3 result sets as you would expect. Every time you call `NextResult()` on the `SqlDataReader` you move to the next result set produced by the query. The trick is that those always came in the same order as they're stated in the query. Then you can put the data in an appropriately tagged data structure.

Comment: @Alejandro I do not know about tables orders. I get this query from the outside and I only know the names of the tables.

Comment: @NaserYousefi Client side, there is no such thing as a "table name", just a result set. The only thing you can rely for sure is that when issuing multiple queries together you get the results back in the same order. If you don't know the query itself, you cannot know how to interpret the results.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I almost guessed, but I wanted to make sure there was no other way.

Comment: Think about this. What if the query came from a join of multiple tables. What would the "table name" be?

Comment: @SeanLange it's would be #FromJoin_TempTable ;) I said I have multiple temp table select and I want to read each one by it's name.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment at all. But the dotnet engine is not going to evaluate your query and see if there is only 1 table and give the resultset table that name. Look at a query just in sql server, you don't get the table name in the result window. It is just a nameless grid with rows.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm sorry if I talk like Martians. My English is still poor. Anyway thanks, I got my answer. I just needed to be sure.

Comment: LOL you don't talk like a martian. I just didn't understand what you were saying. :) Glad you have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from #temp1
union 
select * from #temp2
union
select * from #temp3
```

Remember that #temp1 is a global temp table that exists only as long as a session that created it is still running or some other processing is referring to it. Which means in a C# program there is a very good chance it will be gone by the time you get to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my tables are different.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a dataset that will store all the returned tables. 
Here is a sample

```
 DataSet dsPrograms = new DataSet();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
 SqlCommand cmdArcResponseHandler = new SqlCommand();
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection);
 if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
 {
     conn.Open();
 }
 cmdArcResponseHandler.CommandText = @"select * from #temp1;
                                       select * from #temp2;
                                       select * from #temp3;"
 cmdArcResponseHandler.CommandTimeout = 120;
 cmdArcResponseHandler.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmdArcResponseHandler.Connection = conn;
 da.SelectCommand = cmdArcResponseHandler;
 da.Fill(dsPrograms);
 ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table 1";
 ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table 2";
 ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table 3";
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: This is not my answer. I had mentioned, "not by index" but thanks for your reply.

Comment: Tables returned by a SQL query will not gain names automatically. You will need to assign table names to them.